# How to execute a jQuery code together with Ext.js element creation

Tags: jquery, extjs

I have this in Ext Grid code snippet

```
header: 'Player',
dataIndex: 'SoundFile',
width: 600,
renderer: function (value)
    {
     if (value != null) {

        return '<div id="jquery_jplayer_' + value + '"></div>'
   }
       else
         return 'n/a'
   }
```

The `<div id="jquery_jplayer_' + value + '"></div>` is the element being created.

What I need is that after each element is created and added to DOM, I need to execute the following JS code.

```
$('#jquery_jplayer_' + value).jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    m4a: "/audio.m4a?id=" + $(this).id
                });
            },
            play: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
            },
            swfPath: "jQuery.jPlayer.2.5.0",
            supplied: "m4a",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_" + value,
            wmode: "window",
            smoothPlayBar: true,
            keyEnabled: true
        });
```

How do I execute this JS for every element created by the Ext Grid?

For some reason, jQuery can't access `<div id="jquery_jplayer_' + value + '"></div>` at all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it maybe when you are executing the jquery statement. The Ext markup probably hasn't been generated yet, and you will have to wait longer in the component lifecycle. I would personally try to attach on an event on [GridView](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.View-event-itemadd)